# What if connection will be refused while upgrading Ubuntu?

Tags: upgrade, updates

Can I resume downloading if Ubuntu 16.04 will lost connection for a while?

upd: while I was upgrading from 16.04 to 16.10 with losted connection, it started from the place where download ended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, it first downloads all necessary packages then starts upgrading. You can even stop the upgrade process yourself and start it again after a while.

It's even possible to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the process   for some second then start it again using `fg`.

Answer (score 0):

If your connection is going to go out during the download, I would suggest ordering a USB stick or DVD stick from a distributor that creates the media, rather than downloading yourself.  It may cost some cash, but it will probably be better than trying to download it 50 times.

That said, if your connection is going to go down, and you're not using the official torrent for downloading, then your download will likely get interrupted and you'll have to start over.  The torrent is capable of being started and stopped without much issue, but that's not the case for standard FTP-based or HTTP-based download methods.